# MySQL service in XAMPP is not starting in Windows 10

Tags: mysql, xampp

while I am trying to start MySQL in XAMPP, it's saying-

```
Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

After that, nothing is happening...

I am using XAMPP-7.0.1.

Comment: Some other program might be using the same port....

Comment: I tried different port, but it remains same.